# How can I use a component like(panel,anchorpane) from another Controller in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

In my project i am adding a new fxml file inside a scrollpane using menubox at start menubox is setvisible(false); now after calling a fxml inside scrollpane that contains a button now inside the controller i made a function which makes menubox setvisible(true)

**My complete codes:**

ContentNavigator.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

/**

 */
public class ContentNavigator {

    //fxml files
    public static String CONTENT1 = "masterLogin.fxml";
    public static String CONTENT2 = "FeesAddItem.fxml";
     public static String CONTENT3 = "home.fxml";


    private static DashboardController mainController;

    public static void setController(DashboardController controller){
        ContentNavigator.mainController = controller;
    }

    public static void loadContent(String fxmlFile){
        try {
            mainController.setContent(
                    (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(ContentNavigator.class.getResource(fxmlFile))
            );
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ContentNavigator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

.

```
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
           FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        AnchorPane mainWindow = (AnchorPane) loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("masterboard.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainWindow);

       scene.getStylesheets().add("css/main.css");

        stage.setTitle("JavaFX");

        stage.setScene(scene);
         stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        stage.show();

        DashboardController controller = loader.getController();
        ContentNavigator.setController(controller);
        ContentNavigator.loadContent(ContentNavigator.CONTENT1);

    }
```

masterboard controller

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
   menubox.setVisible(false);
   AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(content1, 0.0);

    }
```

[image: Project snapshot]

At start of project a make  `menubox.setVisible(false);` but during running i want to make `menubox` set visible true but inside `ContentNavigator.loadContent(ContentNavigator.CONTENT1);`

`CONTENT1` fxml contain a button on clicking that button i want `menubox` set visible true.
tell me the way through which i can make it.

Comment: Surely you just want to expose the size of the panel, not the panel itself? There are many techniques for this: a great summary is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html

Comment: yes i want to get the size of panel and set for next window. but the problem is that when i make my panel `public static` it gives me an error

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to make the panel `public`, and certainly have no idea what this has to do with `static`. All you need to do is pass the new controller the current dimensions of the panel when you switch windows. Read the linked discussion for ways to do that.

Comment: so what would i do to get dimensions of the panel  and pass it to next controller.

Comment: Sorry, contrived to paste the wrong link in. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/

Comment: i am new to javfx so all this thing are bouncing above my head can you explain it in simple way.

Comment: Edit your question with more details on how you are opening the new view from the current view (post some code). Not sure I can make it any simpler than it is in the link but I can try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structure is not really clear to me (is "masterboard controller" the same as `DashboardController`?), but I think I get enough of it.

In the masterboard controller, just create and expose a `BooleanProperty` to determine if the menu is showing or not:

```
private final BooleanProperty menuShowing = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "menuShowing", false);
public final void setMenuShowing(boolean showing) {
    menuShowing.set(showing);
}
public final boolean isMenuShowing() {
    return menuShowing.get();
}
public BooleanProperty menuShowingProperty() {
    return menuShowing ;
}
```

and then in your initialize method bind the visible property of the menu to the `menuShowingProperty`:

```
public void initialize() {
    menuBox.visibleProperty().bind(menuShowing);
}
```

Now when you load new content, you just have to give the controller for the content the reference to the `menuShowing` property. The easiest way to do this is something like:

```
// controller for individual content
public class ContentController {
    private BooleanProperty menuShowingProperty ;
    public void setMenuShowingProperty(BooleanProperty menuShowingProperty) {
        this.menuShowingProperty = menuShowingProperty ;
    }

    public void initialize() {
        // ...
    }

    // handler method for button that shows menu:
    @FXML
    private void showMenu() {
        menuShowingProperty.set(true);
    }
}
```

Now when you load the content, do something like:

```
public static void loadContent(String fxmlFile){
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(ContentNavigator.class.getResource(fxmlFile));
        AnchorPane pane = loader.<AnchorPane>load();
        Object controller = loader.getController();
        if (controller instanceof ContentController) {
            ContentController contentController = (ContentController) controller ;
            contentController.setMenuShowingProperty(mainController.menuShowingProperty());
        }
        mainController.setContent(pane);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ContentNavigator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

There are lots of other ways to handle this.

Comment: but i want to know how you have done this. with only little data .

Comment: but i can't change `AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(content1, 0.0);` to      ` AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(content1, 157.0);`

Comment: Don't hard-code the layout. `AnchorPane`s are rarely useful for anything that changes. Use something else, `BorderPane` might be best. That's really a different question entirely.

Comment: @user3204934 James can do it cause he's a telepathic genius and he has *lots* of experience developing and answering questions ;-)